# Missing Standard Library Components

Tags: c++, c++17, clion, std

I'm currently working on a project with C++17 and I have trying to make use of certain libraries (such as `variant` and `optional`). However, my IDE cannot find these (I'm using CLion). What would be the best way to debug this issue? I want to know if I truly do not have these installed (although they are part of the STD Library so I would think this unlikely) or if there is an issue with my editor...

Comment: Does code which is using `optional` and `variant` compile? If yes, the problem is with the IDE. You may want to look in its settings for an option to enable a particular C++ standard version.

Comment: Find out the version of your compiler. Try adding `-v` option to the compiler command line. May be there is an option to choose a compiler in the IDE, look for that.